# Why doesn't static routing on packet tracer work here?

Tags: networking, routes

Hello im doing a static routing on packet tracer but i cant get it to work. I need PC0 to be able to ping PCH-1. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide more information about your exact setup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.